# How do I find the Recaptcha ID?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, recaptcha

I've been stuck on something for the past day. I'm building a RoR bot, and part of it involves signing up for an email account with mail.com. I've automated all the filling out of the form, apart from the captcha (Recaptcha).

I'll be using the deathbycaptcha Ruby gem. However, in order to have the captcha solved, I'll need to get either its ID or its URL. While this shows up when I "enable form details" with the Firefox Web Developer toolbar, it doesn't seem to be in the source. How can I find it out? I'm using Watir.

Thanks!

Joe

http://service.mail.com/registration.html

Comment: I find the irony of this funny. You are trying to write a bot that can sign up for an account but the site has an anti-bot mechanism in place that you're having trouble getting past.  Care to humor us as to the legitimate reason why you need to automate account creation on a 3rd party service? ;-)

Comment: hmm. Define legitimate :D (although don't worry, it won't be for spamming email sending, just receiving confirmation emails for signing up at a few websites) - again, not stuff like spamming forums with stupid unreadable posts, but creating blogs at tumblr with unique content, thereby helping their Google rankings, while not really having any effect on site usage :)

Comment: heh, I knew replying to that was a bad idea. Downvote received :D

Comment: @Joe How does your bot create unique content? If, indeed, it does, you're one step away from creating the first true AI artist. Otherwise you're just loading the internet with more junk and calling it SEO.

Comment: I'm sorry, but due to now receiving a second downvote as a result of my commenting on this, I'm going to abstain from commenting further. However, I can vouch that it is genuine, unique, informative content.

Comment: Oh, and looks like someone's actually spent their time looking through my questions, just to downvote. Good to see some of you are doing something really useful with your time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recaptcha challenge id is the code that comes after the k in the recaptcha URL.

They just ran it through a function rather than just displaying it in the source.

Their site key is 6LdKsrwSAAAAAHjmh-jQNZ7zskPDs1gsY-WNXAKK

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find the recaptcha URL:

http://service.mail.com/registration.html

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, it's really appreciated :) And yeah, I've noticed mail.com rotate the ids of all the elements each time the page is loaded, plus the Google JS isn't too fun to read. My Javascript knowledge isn't great, and I'm not sure what the code inside this means:
`RecaptchaStr_el={visual_challenge:"\u039f\u03c0\u03c4\u03b9\u03ba\u03ae \u03c0\u03c1\u03cc\u03ba\u03bb\u03b7\u03c3\u03b7",` - I can't quite work out where to go from here. This is the readme for the Deathbycaptcha API: http://rubydoc.info/gems/deathbycaptcha/4.1.2/frames although I'd understand if (continued..)

Comment: It's alright. I've done a few bots in my day.
So I'll throw you a bone here. It helps to use the noscript URL http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LdKsrwSAAAAAHjmh-jQNZ7zskPDs1gsY-WNXAKK